# Find key in string and only show the part after the key characters

Tags: ruby, string, if-statement, wikipedia

I have a string with a lot of text in it, its a wikipedia string and I really don't want all of it, just a part.

The problem I have is the first section of the string. It sometimes looks like this.

```
{{olika betydelser}} {{Ortsfakta Sverige | ortnamn = Höganäs | form = [[Tätort]]<br>[[Centralort]] | slogan = | smeknamn = | bild = | bildtext = | vapen = | landskap = [[Skåne]] | län = [[Skåne län]] | kommun = [[Höganäs kommun]] | församling = [[Höganäs församling]] | koordinat = | höjdläge = | lat_g = 56 | lat_m = 12 | lat_s = | lat_NS = N | long_g = 12 | long_m = 34 | long_s = | long_EW = E | areaort = {{Stat/Sverige/Tätorter/Areal| 3488 }} | invort = {{Stat/Sverige/Tätorter/Befolkning| 3488 }} | invår = {{Stat/Sverige/Tätorter/Befolkning| år }} | täthet = auto | grundades = | postort = HÖGANÄS | postnummer = 263 XX | riktnummer = 042 | tätortskod = 3488 | positionskarta = Skåne | positionskartnamn = Sweden Scania location map.svg | karttext = | prickpos x = 32 | prickpos y = 105 | fotnot = | invnot = {{Stat/Sverige/Tätorter/Befolkning| ref }} }}<!-- Slut på Mall:Ortsfakta Sverige -->
```

And in those cases I want to exclude the upper part but take the part below.

```
[[Fil:Hoganas_hamn.jpg|miniatyr|Höganäs Hamn.]] [[Fil:Hoganas_hamn_kvickbadet.jpg|miniatyr|Höganäs Hamn - Kvickbadet.]] [[Fil:Höganäs Jefast ny redigerad-1.jpg|miniatyr|Jefasthuset sett från väster med en del av den nya bryggan vid Kvickbadet.]] '''Höganäs''' är en [[tätort]] och [[centralort]] i [[Höganäs kommun]] i [[Skåne län]]. Höganäs blev stad 1936. Ursprungligen är Höganäs ett [[fiskeläge]] kring vilket en [[gruvindustri]] utvecklades för brytning av [[kol (bränsle)|kol]] och [[lera|leror]] för tillverkning av [[eldfast]] [[keramik]] ([[Höganäskrus]]). Gruvindustrin är numera nedlagd. == Historia == Fiskeläget Höyenaess (Höganäs) finns omnämnd första gången 1488. Från 1569 och århundradena framåt bestod det av 20 hushåll, något färre under peståren på 1700-talet. [[Höganäs AB|Höganäsbolaget]] grundades 1797, då gruvverksamheten tog fart. Denna gruvverksamhet fanns kvar i bygden fram tills mitten av 1960-talet. Efter att tidigare ha ingått i [[Väsby socken]] bildade Höganäs på 1850-talet en självständig församling....
```

What I was thinking of is to write a method that checks if

```
if <!-- Mall: xxx -->
```

Where xxx is dynamic exists and in that case exclude the first part.

I'm using the gem [Wikipedia-client](https://github.com/kenpratt/wikipedia-client) to receive wikipedia info.

I'm pretty novice and aint looking for a complete solution but a hint from where to start.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: *an* wikipedia string? Also, yes what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Romain
Well, I'm really novice about this, I'm not looking for a complete solution but a hint from where to start. Sorry for not being clear about that.

Comment: @pguardiario
I have updated my question, sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: The "part below" isn't even part of the first string. Or do you want to extract the name "Höganäs" and then fetch that page?

Comment: @MichaelKohl the part below is a part of the string and I want to extract the second part and exclude the first part.

Comment: @ MichaelKohl I think what he is looking for is this: `/Mall:.*\s+-->(.*)\z/`. It's all one line. He just split it up in the question.

Comment: @seph: Guess you are right. Well, I guess he cas just take your regex and plug it into my answer below.

Comment: @MichaelKohl - I did put the regex seph posted and it worked, thanks alot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description of what you want is very vague and you don't show any code, but does this help?

```
s =~ /Mall:(.*)\s+-->/ && puts($1)
# prints "Ortsfakta Sverige"
```

The longer version:

```
if s =~ /Mall:(.*)\s+-->/
  puts $1
end
```

Or if you don't like the Perlish `=~`:

```
if m = s.match(/Mall:(.*)\s+-->/)
  puts m[1]
end
# also prints "Ortsfakta Sverige"
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear enough, my english... I don't want the line between the <--- ---> but the lines after that part and exclude the part before and the <--- --->...